# Add character a place in String

Tags: java, arrays, string, stringbuffer

I'm trying to make a method that shall help me to spell world right. After `addChar` have return its work based on the input `"famili"`, I want the result array to contain the word `"familiy"`. Now the method removes a character from the string and replace it with the current char in `alpha[]`, can someone please give me some help to make this method to add the char from `alpha[]` between two characters and not delete one to get space.

```
class Main {
       char [] alpha = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
                        'l', 'm','n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'y', 'z'};
        public static void main(String [] args) {

            Main m = new Main();
            String [] result = m.addChar("famil");
        }

        public String[] addChar(String word) {

            String [] words = new String[word.length() * alpha.length];
            int k = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {
                    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(word);
                    buf.setCharAt(j, alpha[i]);
                    words[k++] = buf.toString();
                }
            }
            return words;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the [insert](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#insert%28int,%20char%29) method of the `StringBuffer` class in place of `setCharAt`.

[**Working link**](http://www.ideone.com/zFLYG)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably solve it like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++)
        words[k++] = word.substring(0, j) + alpha[i] + word.substring(j);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [LinkedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).